# List publications by same Author on Staff page

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I'm using the biblio module to manage publications on my site. I've a content of type "Staff" that display all workers. These workers have publications that are listed on the publication page (using the biblio module). 
Now the Staff node has a field name (wich content the workers first and last name). Now I want to list all biblio (publications) that has the same "Author name" as "Staff name" on a staff page.
The idea is to link Staff name with biblio Authors name, and use this to list every publication containing this workers (staff) name on this particular workers page. 
At the end, I'll habe to add pulbications just once and they will be listed on every workers page containing the name of the author.
How can i achieve this? I've tried everyting i could, but could not find a solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use views and add a relationship to the author inside the view

Comment: I already try that but can't because it's not a site user who post the publication, but the site admin. So the publication author is always the admin of the site.